# Finding transfered ETH

Tags: wallets

On January 9, 2018, I transferred some ETH to a wallet. I cannot find it. All I have is the wallet it was sent to using https://etherscan.io.

On the same day, I created a file on my desktop called "wallet." It is 692 characters which is alphanumeric with two == at the end. I am assuming this is where it is. How can I use this info to send it to an online wallet?

Comment: From the description it seems to be a base64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end, it doesn't seem one of the usual wallet formats. Do you remember how it was generated? Which wallet did you use?

Comment: I dont, is there anyway to use this file and try a bunch of them? It would be great to unlock it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen a similar wallet. If you decode the base64 file and it looks like a json file it could be a utc wallet.